# How can I optimise and speed up react js app with multiple tabs

Tags: reactjs, optimization

I have a react application with multiple tabs, in each tab we can add one or multiple highcharts. Once we reach the third tab, the application becomes very slow, took more than 15 seconds to do actions like adding new tab, delete tab, adding or removing highcharts.
I'm already using functions of optimisation like memo, useMemo, useCallback, ...
So I'm wondering if there is a possibility to unmount or kill the already visited tabs without hiding them in order to save the memory for the active tab. If you have any idea of how I can modify the architecture in order to speed up the application, because, I'm wondering how google chrome for example handle multiple tabs without decreasing the performance.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) to render only the active tab, leaving the others out of the dom until they are needed.

Comment: Thank you Peter for your response, I already used conditional rendering with lazy loading for tab components inside the parent component tabsGroup which is handling tabs children by fonctions like, addTab, renameTab, deleteTab,.. but the app still slow when I want to move from a tab to another for example.

Comment: Could you post a codesandbox to illustrate the issue (or a simplified version of it)?

Comment: Yes, sure. I'll create a codesandbox and share it. Thanks Peter.

Comment: Hi Peter, Thank you for your help. Finally, I removed the content of my tabs from the DOM using conditional rendering and now it's working fine for me. Thanks.

Comment: Great, glad to hear. Please mark the question as answered if you think it helped to solve the problem.